# mat-divider not appearing between mat-toolbar-row

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying angular material and don't understand why divider is rendering on top in browser.
In my understanding it should come between toolbar 1 and toolbar 2.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>This is toolbar 1.</span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <span>This is toolbar 2</span>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

On browser it renders like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

because mat-toolbar component is using content projections like this :

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<ng-content select="mat-toolbar-row"></ng-content>
```

so all mat-toolbar-rows are coming to the bottom.
if you wrap your divider like this, it'll fix the issue.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>This is toolbar 1.</span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
     <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <span>This is toolbar 2</span>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: just learned something! Didn't know about `select` attribute for `ng-content`!